# How to display php array images vertically by 2 each in horizontal

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fetch out images from a popular category in php. The images are fetching correctly but i could not able to control the images in html.

I want the image as below:

[IMAGE1](http://s12.postimage.org/bpyeo49kp/need_this_block.jpg?noCache=1360233957)

But getting this image block:

[IMAGE2](http://s7.postimage.org/kur70jyyf/getting_this_block.jpg?noCache=1360234096)

I am trying to put this image in a table format in html page:

```
<table width=200>
 <tr>
  <td width=200><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/[var.images;block=td;comm]" width=100 /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me out? Sorry for bad english!

Comment: difficult to understand your exact requirement

Comment: please check the image1 and image2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to get this done. It will give you more flexibility.

```
<div id="maincontainer" style="width:400px;">
 // run your foreach loop here
<img src='pathtoimage' style='width:200px; float:left;' />
// for each loop ends here
</div>
```

this gives you a lot of flexibility. considering that img is a block element it automatically falls to the bottom line after the maximum width of its containing div(maincontainer) has reached.

Comment: this should do exactly what you want to do. also this is a very simple solution, you should never put inline css tags.
move them to a css file and include the file in your code.